# Increasing Cart quantity RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I am trying to create a basic setup in my cart controller that will allow me to incrementally increase the quantity value of products added to the cart if an Item record already exists.

I currently have:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def create  
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

    if @item.new_record?
        @item = Item.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
    else
        @item.increment! :quantity
    end
    redirect_to cart_path(current_cart.id)
end

end
```

However I keep getting the error `undefined method`new_record?' for nil:NilClass`

Any help people can offer to solve this really would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't anywhere declared @item. before this thats why the error is coming

try this code

```
def create  
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

if !current_cart.items.exists?(:product_id => @product.id)
    @item = Item.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
else
    current_cart.items.find(:first, :conditions =>{:product_id => @product.id}).increment! :quantity
end
redirect_to cart_path(current_cart.id)
end
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that totally makes sense. How can I define a @item as an item within a specific cart? Thanks

Comment: i Guess i have supplimented the code also in the edit try it and telll whether it runs or not

Comment: It worked to add the item to the cart but then was giving this error when trying to increment the quantity `undefined method `increment!' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x60a4880>` Thanks :)

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much I have spent a long time trying to achieve this! Have a great day! :)